# SQL Lookup data in joined table based on LIKE value stored in joined table column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012-express

I am trying to build a query that will look up a product_subcategory based on a reference data in a user entered table and joining two tables together. My database is SQL Server 2012 Express.

First the `products` table has three columns: `Product_id` (unique identifier), `event_id` (INT data type), and `product_category`. (`product_category` needs to be alphanumeric currently varchar(32) data type)

Example `Products` table data:

```
Product_id  event_id    product_category
1           20          100
2           20          105
3           20          200
4           21          100
5           21          200
6           21          203
7           22          105
8           22          207
```

Second the events table has two columns: event_id (unique identifier, INT Data type) and zone (float data type, not sure why this was setup as float, probably should have been INT but its a pre-existing table and I don't want to change it)

```
event_id      zone
20            1
21            2
22            3
```

Third the `subcategory` table has four columns: `subcategory_id` (unique identifier, INT data type), `zone` (joins to `zone` column in `products` table, INT Data type), `category_lookup` (varchar(max) data type), and `product_subcategory` (varchar(50) data type). This is a table that I am creating for this project so I can change the structure or datatypes to be whatever is needed for the project, I don't have that flexibility on the other tables.

Example `Subcategory` table data:

```
subcategory_id  zone    category_lookup    product_subcategory
1               1       '1%'               25
2               1       '2%'               23
3               2       '1%'               26
4               2       '2%'               30
```

I want to build a query that will search the product table and match a `zone`, `product_category`, and `product_subcategory` together based on the value in the `subcategory.category_lookup` column.

The data that I want returned from the query is:

```
product_ID  zone    product_category    product_subcategory
1           1       100                 25
2           1       105                 25
3           1       200                 23
4           2       100                 26
5           2       200                 30
6           2       203                 30
7           3       105                 NULL or 'N/A'
8           3       107                 NULL or 'N/A'
```

The logic behind looking up the matching subcategory will be similar to below: (this is essentially what is stored in the subcategory table) (the text in the “quotes” is what I mean by reference data, and will be user entered)

```
IE... if zone = 1 and product_category “begins with 1” then product_subcategory = 25
IE... if zone = 1 and product_category “begins with 2” then product_subcategory = 23
IE... if zone = 2 and product_category “begins with 1” then product_subcategory = 26
IE... if zone = 2 and product_category “begins with 2” then product_subcategory = 30
```

I do understand that one of the issues with my logic is that if multiple subcategories match to one product then it will throw an error, but I think I can code around that once I get this part of it working

I am fine going a different direction with this project but this is the first way I decided to tackle it. The most important component is that the `product_subcategory`’s are going to be located in a separate user entered table, and there needs to be user entered logic as discussed above to determine the `product_subcategory` based on zone and `product_category`.

I am not a SQL guru at all so I don’t even know where to start to handle this problem. Any advice is appreciated.

Based on answers I have received so far I have come up with this:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.event_id, e.zone, p.product_category, sc.product_subcategory
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN events e on p.event_id = e.event_id
LEFT JOIN SubCategory sc ON e.zone = sc.zone AND CAST(p.product_category as varchar(max)) like sc.category_lookup
```

But unfortunately its only returning NULL for all of the product_subcategory results.

Any additional help is appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: should the last product_category in your expected results be 207?

Comment: Yes sorry 107 was a typo it should have been 207 good catch. I knew I'd have at least one in there

Comment: have tested my answer locally and it works, but will depend on datatypes your end

Comment: have updated my post to reflect your updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick, you will just need to modify the `CAST(p.zone as nchar(10))` to insert the correct data type for your `category_lookup` column, in place of `nchar(10)`, as I assume the `zone` in `Products` is an `int` where as the lookup column is some string based column:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.zone, p.product_category, sc.product_subcategory
FROM Products p
LEFT JOIN SubCategory sc ON p.zone = sc.zone
AND CAST(p.zone as nchar(10)) like sc.category_lookup
```

Based on your updates, the following should work:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.event_id, e.zone, p.product_category, 
       sc.product_subcategory
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN events e on p.event_id = e.event_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN SubCategory sc ON e.zone = sc.zone 
     AND CAST(e.zone as nchar(250)) LIKE CAST(sc.category_lookup as nchar(250))
```

**Update based on comments:**

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.event_id, e.zone, p.product_category, 
       sc.product_subcategory
FROM Products p
INNER JOIN events e on p.event_id = e.event_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN SubCategory sc ON e.zone = sc.zone 
     AND CAST(p.product_category as nchar(250)) LIKE sc.category_lookup
```

Working sample **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/437aa/5)**

Comment: oh hold on - product_category needs to be alphanumeric means it's already a text type ?

Comment: working on testing it now, products.product_category is varchar(32) subcategory.category_lookup is currently varchar(max) and subcategory.product_subcategory is varchar(50)

Comment: should it be AND CAST(p.product_category as nchar(10)) like sc.category_lookup  ?

Comment: i just updated my original post with your suggestions, also there was an additional table that I left out of my original post, I was hoping to uncomplicate it by leaving that out, but it put it back in because its probably relevant. I feel like I am very close but its unfortunately still returning nulls, any additional help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Its unfortunately still returning nulls with that update. I tried to switch out the last line "LIKE sc.category_lookup" for "LIKE '1%'" just to see if i could get any non-null results and when doing that I am able to get data returned. Is is possible that its having trouble converting the data in the column into a format that can be used in the sql statement?

Comment: @Ryan does it work if you change the join to this: `AND CAST(e.zone as nchar(250)) LIKE CAST(sc.category_lookup as nchar(250))` so the types match?

Comment: no unfortunately not, I tested that too. still returns nulls

Comment: I've run both locally with your updates to the table and data types and they work so I can't explain it

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong then. I literally copy and pasted your query into my sql studio, I wonder if there's some setting on my server that needs to be enabled to handle this kind of query. Do you think I am handling this task properly or is there a better route that I should go about to try and accomplish what I am looking to do here? (again, thanks for all your help)

Comment: take a look at this simplified sqlfiddle where i've just included the LIKE clause part: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d39a5e/5 that works fine. please check the data types there are correct against what you have

Comment: wow, I didn't even know this tool existed. This is great for testing. I've been doing it the hard way all along. yes it does appear to be working in your example link so I took it a step further and built out the entire structure. It does return data in the product_subcategory column but its the wrong data. its returning 25 for all zone 1 and 30 for all zone 2. I keep thinking I might just be tackling this problem incorrectly. Here's the link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/437aa/4

Comment: @Ryan updated posted with new fiddle, you were casting zone to the lookup rather than the product category

Comment: very strange, I actually tried changing that too just before sending you that latest fiddle, I had suggested that change a while back but figured maybe it was wrong for some reason. Whats strange is that when I tried it about a half hour ago it returned all nulls in the fiddle and of course its working now. Im lost. Also I tried changing sqlfiddle to sql 2012 but it gives a schema creating failed error.

Comment: I think the failure absoutely has to do with the datatype cast, if I cast the final statement as "LIKE CAST(sc.category_lookup as nchar(250))" then it returns all nulls, thats probably how I had it when i test and it failed a few minutes ago. see link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ecfa/2   I just doublechecked all my datatypes locally and they match the fiddle exactly. do you think the version of SQL could be causing this? or some setting that needs to be enabled on the server?

Comment: perhaps check the collation of the server, the database and the table columns to see if there's any conflict.

Comment: @Tanner I just confirmed that its something wrong with my servers configuration by testing it on a completely different server, works perfectly. Thanks again for the help

Comment: @Tanner I figured out why it was working for you and not for me. I was inserting data into the tables by right clicking on the table and going to "edit rows" and in the subcategory row I was saving the 1% as '1%' (with the quotes) where when you were doing an insert it was leaving out the quotes. if I changed your statement to include triple quotes it brings me right back to where I was and ultimately I decided it would be better if i could store the entire "LIKE '1%'" in that table and dynamically build the statement. Please see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c0574   do you think that's possible?

Comment: that was the wrong fiddle link, heres the correct one: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9c0574/3

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but is this what you're looking for ?

```
select a.product_ID, a.zone, a.product_category, b.product_subcategory
from Products a
inner join Subcategory on ((a.zone = b.zone) and (a.product_category like b.category_lookup))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
select p.product_id, p.zone, p.product_category, isnull(s.product_subcategory,'NA') as product_subcategory
from Products p
left outer join Subcategory s on (s.zone = p.zone and p.product_category like s.category_lookup);
```